# Matrix in Template: how to get total rows?

Tags: templates, matrix

I need to know outside of the Matrix tag pair the total rows that it has. To get total rows within the tag pair, this works for me:

```
{matrix_field_short_name}
   <h1>{total_rows}</h1>
{/matrix_field_short_name}
```

Outside the tag pair, it seems like this should work: `{matrix_field_short_name:total_rows}` per http://pixelandtonic.com/matrix/docs/templates. However, instead of getting an integer, I'm getting the string `http://domain.com/member_uploads/_s:total_rows/slide.jpg`.

My Matrix field is names `images` and it contains the columns `image` (the file) and `caption` (a text field).

Any idea what might be going on?

**EDIT 1: Code Snippet**

```
<h1>{images:total_rows}</h1>                        

{images}                                            
    <div class="{if row_count == 1}active{/if} item">
        <img src="{image:250x250}" alt="{caption}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>{caption}</p>
    </div>  
{/images}
```

Comment: it should work, able to provide additional code from within your template?

Comment: See edit. Everything in `{images}` works as expected. I don't get total rows in the h1.

Comment: what does your exp:channel:entries tag look like? is the above code the only thing in the template?  I assume latest version of matrix, tried re-uploading?

Comment: It looks like a conflict with names. I'd try renaming your matrix field to something else.

Comment: yeah I'd say name conflict is the most probably, go with a strict or firm naming convention for you fields ala http://www.digitalevangelist.net/notes/whats-in-a-name

Comment: I renamed `images` to `member_images`, etc. Now it works. How do I accept an answer?

Comment: If it was written as an answer, you click the little checkmark off to the side of it, but if it was a comment, you can either write your solution as an answer with attribution to the comment, then accept or just accept the next closest answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the name. I've run into that before. I have adapted a matrix naming convention of a small prefix from the matrix field then whatever I need : eg.  seg-images if the matrix field is segments. In your case, it looks like you have images as the matrix field itself. Try naming it something like mx-images.